# How to return number of rows available in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have sentences in a Data frame that I chop them into words and the occurrence  of each word in the data frame, and store them into a Dictionary mapping,I want to return number of rows available in that dictionary, I used **count** but it still returns the full dictionary rather than the number of rows, any ideas what is wrong with my code ?

```
pat = '[' + re.escape(",?!.:;'؛؛؟'-)(؛،؛«/") + ']'

sata = wdata['sentences'].str.replace(pat, '')

dicc = (sata.str.split(expand=True)
        .stack()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('word')
        .reset_index(name='freq'))

countt= dicc.count




print ("vocab size is  : " +   str(countt))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use length of `DataFrame`:

```
countt = len(dicc)
```

Your solution should be changed with [`Series.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html) by one column, but it count with exclude missing values:

```
countt = dicc['freq'].count()
```

For count only values with `5` or more is possible use [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater and then `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
countt_by_condition = dicc['freq'].gt(5).sum()
```

Comment: is there a way to return the vocab size of the freq of words that are more than 5 ? an easy way bro ? @Jezreal

Comment: so any freq with less than 5 or any number  I put it wont be counted for